# Как делать запрос на C# EF на добавление данных в таблицу БД PostgreSQL, в которой есть Unique столбец, чтобы не возвращало ошибку, если есть дубли?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Добавляю сразу большое количество строк.
Если использовать SQL, в INSERT можно дописать ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, чтобы не возвращало ошибку. Если данные дублируются, просто проигнорит их и не будет добавлять

Например, в таблице уже есть nickname1 и nickname2, добавляем несколько строк:

```
INSERT INTO users (nickname)
VALUES ('nickname1'), ('nickname2'), ('nickname3')
ON CONFLICT (nickname) DO NOTHING;
```

Как это сделать с помощью C# + EF?

Comment: Судя по этой теме: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16949 - нет такой возможности. / Можно попробовать добавлять on conflict с помощью [перехватчиков](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors).

Comment: [FlexLabs.Upsert](https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert) - возможно, эта библиотека поможет.

Comment: Обратите внимание на lin2db. Эта ORM имеет [Merge API](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/merge/Merge-API.html). Наверняка это то, что нужно: [InsertWhenNotMatched](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/merge/Merge-API-Description.html#insertwhennotmatched). Можно использовать расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Оно включено в официальный список [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).

Comment: Если используется EF6, а не EF Core, то не знаю, чем помочь. / Укажите точную версию EF.

Comment: Спасибо!) Посмотрю. Использую EF Core